# Trying to reprocess picture in after_update callback leads to infinite loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, paperclip, infinite-loop

I have this model for pictures attached to another model (`Work`):

```
class WorkPicture < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :default_values
  after_update :reprocess_picture, if: :cropping_changed?

  belongs_to :work, inverse_of: :pictures

  has_attached_file    :picture, styles: lambda { |attachment| { big: { geometry: "1500x>", format: :png },
                                                                 thumb: attachment.instance.thumb_options } },
                                 url:             "/pictures/:hash.:extension",
                                 hash_secret:     ENV["PAPERCLIP_SECRET_KEY"]
  validates_attachment :picture, presence:        true,
                                 content_type:    { content_type: /image/ }

  scope :illustrative, -> { where(is_cover: false) }

  # Default values
  def default_values
    self.is_cover = false if self.is_cover.nil?
    self.crop_x = 0 if self.crop_x.nil?
    self.crop_y = 0 if self.crop_y.nil?
  end

  def thumb_options
    return { geometry: "", format: :png, convert_options: "-crop 360x222+#{crop_x.to_i}+#{crop_y.to_i}" }
  end

  private
    def cropping_changed?
      self.crop_x_changed? || self.crop_y_changed?
    end

    def reprocess_picture
      picture.reprocess!
    end
end
```

These pictures serve a dual purpose: if `is_cover` is set to `false`, they're displayed in the gallery page of the work in question. If `is_cover` is set to `true`, they're cropped and used as "icons" for the work in question in a page that lists all works.

On the work edit page you're allowed to change the x and y coordinates of the cropping. This means that the image should be reprocessed once the new coordinates come in, so that the correct area is shown.

To do this, I set up two attributes on the model, `crop_x` and `crop_y`, which store the position of the cropping window. Through `after_update`, I first check if those coordinates have been changed and, if so, I tell Paperclip to reprocess the image to crop it correctly.

When running this code, execution enters an endless loop. I think I've identified the cause of this: `after_update` [doesn't clear](http://blog.quov.is/2011/11/22/the-unintuitive-flushing-of-activerecords-dirty/) the `ActiveRecord::Dirty` attributes (e.g. `self.crop_x_changed?`) to make it more useful to the developer, but when I call `reprocess!` on the picture Paperclip itself makes changes to my model and calls `save`, which in turn causes the `after_update` callback to be triggered again. Since `self.crop_x_changed?` and `self.crop_y_changed?` are still `true` from the beginning of this chain (this is because they seem to only be cleared once `after_update` has been run), this causes my code to call `reprocess!` again, which continues this endless loop.

I've tried many similar variations of this code, but all seem to either loop endlessly or just fail. Is there a way I can make my code perform this function correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a friend's help, I managed to find a way to make it work. Here's how I solved it:

I created a new class `WorkPicture::Recropper` in `app/models/work_picture/recropper.rb` (for comparison, the `work_picture.rb` file is in `app/models/`). Here's the code for it:

```
class WorkPicture::Recropper
  def initialize work_picture
    @work_picture = work_picture
    @crop_x = @work_picture.crop_x
    @crop_y = @work_picture.crop_y
  end

  def recrop
    @work_picture.reload

    if @work_picture.crop_x != @crop_x || @work_picture.crop_y != @crop_y
      @work_picture.picture.reprocess!
    end
  end
end
```

I changed my controller's update action to use `WorkPicture::Recropper`:

```
class WorksController < ApplicationController

  # ... Other actions ...

  def update
    @work = Work.find(params[:id])
    recropper = WorkPicture::Recropper.new(@work.cover_picture)

    if @work.update_attributes(work_params)
      recropper.recrop
      redirect_to @work
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

private

  def work_params
    params.require(:work).permit(:name, :description, :category_id, pictures_attributes: [:crop_x, :crop_y, :is_cover, :picture, :id])
  end
end
```

What I did in a nutshell is instance the recropper by passing it the cover picture before updating its attributes, so that it has a chance to store the old crop coordinates. Once the attributes are updated, the `recrop` method reloads the model and compares the new values of the attributes to the ones it had stored. If they've changed, it reprocesses the picture.

This solution works, but it might not be the cleanest possible. If anybody has a better idea, please let me know.